# How do we link an items nbt numbers to a scoreboard number?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I'm working with my datapack but got stuck with this problem. We're basically connecting nbt numbers into a players scoreboard number.

I'm trying to link an item's nbt to a scoreboard. For example, let's say I have a scoreboard called 'Change'. The item I am holding will have the tag 'CustomItem:1b' and 'Change:1b'.

First, we make the scoreboard 'change'.

```
scoreboard objectives add Change dummy
```

Next, the command detects if the player is holding an item with the nbt 'CustomItem:1b'.

```
execute as @a if entity @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{tag:{CustomItem:1b}}}] run ...
```

Now it checks the item you hold, to see if the number in the nbt 'Change:10b' meaning '10' is different from your current score. I want this to only happen when you first hold the item. If it is different then:

1. give the player the tag Change

```
.... run tag @s[tag=!ChangeDone] add Change
```

2. The player with the tag 'Change' will link the nbt of the item in their hand to the scoreboard. Since the current nbt of the item is 'Change:10b', your score will be changed to 10 in the 'Change' scoreboard
3. Check again if the 'Change:10b' is the same, if it is the same then 'Change' tag is removed and 'ChangeDone' tag is added

```
... run tag @s[tag=Change] add ChangeDone
.... run tag @s remove Change
```

Now I want to detect all players with the tag 'ChangeDone' to see if their item's nbt 'Change:10b' number and score is different again

```
/execute as @a[tag=ChangeDone] ...
```

Now if I change my score with commands to 9 in 'change', the nbt and scoreboard will link again.
But this time the number in the scoreboard will change the nbt of the item, from 'Change:10b' to 'Change:9b' .

From here if my score turns to 8 'Change:10b' will change to 'Change:8b'

Change score 7: 'Change:7b'
change score 6: 'Change:6b'

You get the point

My first thought was to collect the nbt data into a storage similar to

```
execute store result score @s Change run data get entity @s SelectedItem.tag.Damage
```

I feel as if I'm close to figuring this out, but I haven't found out how to do this.

Using this type of command can help us make Custom Durability, gun ammunition, ammunition clips, limited uses, and so much more. Anyone got ideas?